# open street map, is x location in a park?

Tags: google-apps-script, openstreetmap

I am using Google App Script and I need to know if a location is inside a leisure=park area of open street map.

I have been told that It's easy but I can't figure It out. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi Paolo... Stackoverflow is a community where we help each other after they have tried hard themselves and are still struggling. It is best to have a go yourself, write some code, show it here and ask for help on where you are struggling. Otherwise you question gets down voted.

Comment: I fully understand, the sad thing is that when I asked i had no code not because I had not worked on It but because I had really not idea how to even start and i hoped someone could have the right easy answer. Well, i will learn from this :) Ps. I finally found the solution

Answer (score 0):

In case you have my same question here is a good answer.

https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/48449/how-to-get-area-type-given-latlon-coordinates